# How can I recover a deleted Google Apps domain?

Tags: google-workspace, account-management

I have deleted the account for Google Apps by misguidance.  Is there any chance that it can be recovered?  When I try to create a new one for the same domain, it says

> This domain has been registered and is in the process of ownership verification. If you believe this registration was unauthorized, please have your domain administrator contact Google support.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest you write to Google?

Comment: that what im thinking but i could not find any ways, i have asked a question in the google aps forum

Answer (score 5):

It isn't possible to recover an Google Apps account.  You will need to wait a few days (5-7), and then recreate the account, but it appears that all the data will be lost...

See - http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps/thread?tid=248f355aa9627210&hl=en
and
See - http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps/thread?tid=71f0985adea1857c&hl=en

Summary of web threads:

> if you deleted the google apps domain account then it is noway to recovery
>   the data  such as contacts,emails, etc all that was deleted when the google
>   apps domain account was deleted. if you was using the Premier edition it
>   has the Google messages Security and Recovery system by Postini  where it
>   store copies of the emails for 90 days. and if you only had the standard
>   edition then that edition doesn`t have the Postini system.

Answer (score 2):

Fortunately, you *can* “undelete” accounts nowadays, at least recently deleted accounts, and the ability may depend on the edition of Google Apps you're using (we use the Education edition). How: *Control Panel* → *Organisation and Users* → Choose *List recently deleted users* → Select account(s) to undelete → Choose Action *Undelete*.